# Is there a way I can make a CSS selector put a "-" before a heading?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS selector:

```
h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Is there some way that I could make it change a heading:

```
Example
```

to

```
- Example
```

Comment: Is it required that you do in pure CSS and not in JS or JQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [pseudo element `:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to add content before it as such:

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h3:before {
  content: '- ';
}
```

```html
<h3>Example</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h3::before {
  content: "- ";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Something like that should suffice

Comment: why `display: inline-block;`? And why the font-size?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

CSS

```
h1:before{
  content:'-';
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t0b814ah/)

Answer (score 1):

you canuse :before pseudo element

```css
h3:before
{
  content:"- ";
}
```

```html
 <h3>Example</h3>
```

for more
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp